# HTML form input steals focus/ focus gets shifted

Tags: html

For some reason the focus keeps getting shifted from any of the address field to the credit card field on my HTML form.

So onclick of address fields, the focus goes back to the credit card field.

It's probably something really simple, but can anyone help?

http://jsfiddle.net/xYbsz/

```
<form name='order-validation'>
<p><label>email: <input type="email" title="email" id="emailAddress" name="email"   value=""></label></p>

<p>
Phone: <select name="countrycode" style="display: inline;">
<option value="44" selected>UK (+44)</option> 
<option value="1">USA (+1)</option> 
<option value="213">Algeria (+213)</option> 
</select><input type="tel" name="phone" id="id_tel" required pattern="(\+?\d[-.]*){7,13}" title="international, national or local phone number"/></p>
<img class="cc-img" id="visa-card-img" src="visa.jpg" />
<img class="cc-img" id="mastercard-card-img" src="mastercard.jpg" />
<img class="cc-img" id="amex-card-img"src="american-express.jpg" />
<p><label>credit card: <input type="text" id="cc_number" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}"><br />
<img class="cc-security-code" id="visa-sec-code" src="cvv.gif" />

<img class="cc-security-code" id="amex-sec-code" style="display: none;" src="amex-sec-code.gif" /><br />
Address:
<input type="text" name="newCreditCardStreet" size="35" tabindex="5" value="" id="id_creditCardStreet"><br />
Town/City:
<input type="text" name="newCreditCardLocality" size="35" tabindex="5" value="" id="id_creditCardLocality"><br />
Country:
<input type="text" name="country" id="id_country">
<p><input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
<p id="test"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

The label tag for `cc_number` is not closed.

```
  <label for="cc_number">credit card:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="cc_number" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}"><br />
```

Also I noticed in the markup the label tags are wrapping the inputs.  This is unnecessary:

```
<label>email: 
    <input type="email" title="email" id="emailAddress" name="email"   value="">
</label>
```

Instead use the `for` attribute:

```
<label for="emailAddress">email:</label>
<input type="email" title="email" id="emailAddress" name="email"   value="">
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/xYbsz/1/

Comment: Knew it was something obvious! Thanks Kevin.

Comment: Useful pages: [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org), [HTML Reference](http://www.w3schools.com)